# Rails fails with Vue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, vue.js

I set up new project with Rails 5.1.4, webpacker 3.0 and Vue.js, i used webpack doc to install Vue with Rails. 
When I hit foreman with my Procfile the Vues part fails.

[image]

I thought wepacker is smart enough for installing all the basic stuff to run app...

Edit: 
***bundle exec rails webpacker:install:vue***
Gave me this, still doesnt work

```
const { dev_server: devServer } = require('@rails/webpacker').config

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const inDevServer = process.argv.find(v => v.includes('webpack-dev-server'))
const extractCSS = !(inDevServer && (devServer && devServer.hmr)) || isProduction

module.exports = {
  test: /\.vue(\.erb)?$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: { extractCSS }
  }]
}
```

Comment: Have you run `yarn` in your console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["You may need an appropiate loader to handle this file type" webpack and vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031720/you-may-need-an-appropiate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-webpack-and-vue)

Comment: @VitaliiProdan Yep, I hit the yarn and all is up-to-date

Comment: You also need to configure vue-loader for single file components to work. The extension for such components is .vue.

Comment: There is a vue loader in my config/webpack/loaders dir.

Answer (score 1):

As webpacker problems don't stop in development, but make deployment more difficult, i just want to mention that it is very easy to avoid the whole issue. Just don't use webpacker, unless you know you really really have to.

Use the cdn's where vue is. Write app code into rails templates (i use halm and either javascript or ruby2js filter). Even small components can be done that way, or then with the x-template syntax.

Works a charm for small scale

Answer (score 0):

So I get rid off this.

I installed vue with rails manually and added vue loader with yarn command 
*yarn add vue vue-loader vue-template-compiler* without from "." at the end.
Thanks for help guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

To get the Javascript dependencies installed so that webpacker can run:

```
bundle install
yarn install
```

Then restart the `bin/webpack-dev-server` since it rarely likes large changes or files moving around.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Vue on Rails after 2018, you should use the Vue on Rails app template

```
rails new app -m https://vueonrails.com/vue -d postgresql
```

It ships with the default configuration and shortcuts. Check out all the things that it ships with -> http://github.com/vueonrails/vueonrails