# How to fix the error "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-vue

I have a fresh Laravel installation. On compiling files using `npm run dev VUE` I get a file error

> "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file"

**Laravel Verion**: "^8.12"

**Package.json**

```
 "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
```

**blade file**

```
 <div id="app">
        <hello></hello>
    </div>
    <script src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
import  Vue from  'vue'    
Vue.component('hello', require('./hello.vue').default);
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**Hello.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        Hello World!
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

**npm run dev**

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|     <div>
|         Hello World!
```

Comment: @KamleshPaul npm run dev

Comment: @KamleshPaul same error with Captal.
ERROR in ./resources/js/vue/components/Hello.vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|     <div>
|          Hello World!

Comment: @KamleshPaul these commands use. npm i vue -D . npm i vue-loader -D . npm i vue-template-compiler -D.then npm install. then for compiling the file npm run dev.
 "postcss": "^8.1.14"` it seems missing.i'm not using postcss.in webpack.mix.js
only this line.i've remoed for postcss.mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');

Comment: @KamleshPaul after install   "postcss": "^8.2.2". same error..

Answer (score 183, accepted):

as your using `laravel-mix 6` it have different config for webpack.mix.js

### webpack.mix.js

use `.vue()`

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
    ]);
```

ref link https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/upgrade

Comment: Thanx bro .mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue(); slove the issue

Comment: i can't because of point less than < 15,will do in future.

Comment: And how do I refresh the settings of my project so that it applies the change?

Comment: Do you know any way to use this and also add scss?

Comment: It works, I tried differently but this is the only solution that works for me.

Comment: Thank you for this. Laravel Nova does not document this anywhere.

Comment: It worked for me! Thank you. In addition to adding .vue(), when trying to run the command mix watch --hot in the terminal, the following message was displayed:

"dditional dependencies must be installed. This will only take a moment.
 
        Running: npm install vue-template-compiler vue-loader@^15.9.7 --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps
 
        Finished. Please run Mix again."

After running this command, I was able to compile mix successfully.

Comment: There is a way for @vue/cli 4.5.13? in my case returns me with /echarts/lib/chart/sunburst/SunburstPiece.js

Comment: In a simple Vue development environment without Laravel, I've used ".vue()"  as below. It works fine & saved my time. mix.js('src/app.js', 'dist').sass('src/app.scss', 'dist').vue();

Answer (score 18):

If anyone still encounters this issue, here how I figure out the cause in my case and it's actually a Laravel mix 6 configuration issue for Vue support.

You can check the documentation for more details : [Laravel mix 6 upgrade documentation](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/upgrade)

**But let me explain it in short here...**

I was using Laravel mix 6 (you may probably use the same if you created a fresh Laravel 8 project) and according to its official documentation "**Laravel Mix 6 ships with support for the latest versions of numerous dependencies, including webpack 5, PostCSS 8, Vue Loader 16, and more**". So no need for you to add vue loader although the error states it.

You rather need to tell explicitly Laravel mix 6 to support vue, here what they say "***Laravel Mix was originally built to be quite opinionated. One of these opinions was that Vue support should be provided out of the box***. ***Any call to*** `mix.js()` ***would instantly come with the benefit of Vue single-file components***.

***Though we're not removing Vue support by any stretch, we have extracted Vue to its own "featured flag"***: `mix.vue()`.

Here what I did.

**First option**

```
// You can simply use this
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.vue()
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
]);
```

**Second option**

```
// Or this if you want to extract styles as well
// Feel free to check the documentation for more customisations
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.vue({
    extractStyles: true,
    globalStyles: false
})
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        //
]);
```

Comment: Do you know any way to use this and also add scss?

Comment: This saves my life!

Answer (score 5):

here i do with the some problem

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.sourceMaps();
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, thanks to Paul for this clarification which saved my evening :)

After that the compilation worked for me, but an error appeared in the console when I reloaded the page:

```
Vue.use is not a function
```

For those who would be in the same case, in your app.js file, you must replace the line :

```js
window.Vue = require('vue');
```

With :

```js
window.Vue = require('vue').default;
```

Answer (score 1):

`mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue() .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [ // ]);`

Or

`npm install vue-template-compiler vue-loader@^15.9.7 --save-dev --legacy-peer-deps`

try both..