# VueJS not rendering template content

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I recently started converting my laravel 8 project to VueJS, but it does not seem to render it's template content.
Well, i used the following commands to include basic structure of Vue: `php artisan ui vue && npm install`

app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue').default;

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Main view:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
</head>
<body id="app">
    <example-component></example-component>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Npm build works well, there're no errors. But unfortunately, the templates content is not visible in the frontend. Everything I see is the vue-tag itself like:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Vue You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607153/laravel-vue-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type)

Comment: Not really, I'm still using laravel-mix 5.0.5

Comment: then try `npm i && npm run dev`

Comment: Same, building works fine but still no frontend output. :/

Comment: try hard reload or clear browser cache then it will show `hold down Ctrl and then press F5 on your keyboard`

Comment: These are always me default keys to clear the cache. But I took a look depper into the console output. Now, it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of undefined" Where does it need to be registered?

Comment: `window.Vue = require('vue').default;` to `window.Vue = require('vue')` try this

Comment: please remove `default` from `window.Vue = require('vue').default;`

Comment: Thank you both, it seems to work! Can you explain, what "default" is used for in this case? And is there a way to hide the vue tag inside of the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the root component shouldn't be mounted in body element, you've to do something like :

```
<body >
   <div id="app">
    <example-component></example-component>
  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

and remove `default` from `window.Vue = require('vue').default;` :

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```