# Login and Registration page not appearing right what to do?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have done in terminal

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel Push "8.0"
cd Push 
composer require laravel/ui
```

Then change package.json file to :
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/package.json#L12

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
npm install --save-dev cross-env
npm install vue 
npm install vue-loader
npm install vue-template-compiler
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

in webpack.mix.js do [How to fix the error "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607153/how-to-fix-the-error-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-typ)

```
npm install&&npm run dev
```

And so does my login and registration not appear right what to do different.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ab8G.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfTAv.png)

It should appear like in picture 2 it seems like it's broken

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What does 'not appear right' means? Isn't it appear at all? And have you ran 'php artisan migrate'?

Comment: @JohnJohvy look at the pictures do you know a fix.

Comment: Well, according to image 1, it looks like the path for the assets is wrong. Please share an example for the stylesheets link in that page, and check your APP_URL value in the .env file.