# Unexpected Token in Vue 3 Mix with Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a problem while running my app with Vue JS 3 (Options API) with Laravel 8. Here's the problem I got.

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/components/App.vue 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <template>
|     <div>
|         <h1>Hello Gago</h1>
```

I already installed vue-loader via `npm install vue-loader@next` I would like to know how to fix this problem. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I already fixed the problem here with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607153/how-to-fix-the-error-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-typ?rq=2 Thanks!